# How to align bottom of legend to the X axis line?

Tags: javascript, css, charts, highcharts

I want to align bottom of legend to X axis.

I was thinking about something like that:

```
var legend= chart.legend;
var legend.Y= Chart.plotTop + Chart.plotHeight - legend.legendHeight;
```

but, there is no property Y of object legend. Could you provide some sample code or give some tip?

I want also to align chart title to left Y axis labels. How can I get width or property "left" of top y axis label?

Charts will be generated by users, and they should have a possibility to format charts as they want(for example make visible or hide axis category title). And because of that I do not want to use fixed values, because once it would work ok, once not.

Thanks

link to image: http://www.fotosik.pl/pokaz_obrazek/pelny/12dadc5d85228db9.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edited**

As for axes:
Right title is simple - move left for 10.
Left is harder. You could use the top tick (its x position) and length of label of that tick.

As of alignment of the legend you can use translate and get chart's size from variables shown in example below `(chart.plotTop + chart.plotHeight - legend.legendHeight)`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/0ur3L0pL/8/

```
$(function () {
    var primText = 'primary',
        secoText = 'secondary',
        hidden = $('<span id="hidden" style="display:none; ont-size:11px; "></span>');
    $('body').append(hidden);

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            marginTop: 80
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -60 //center
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: primText,
                rotation: 0,
                align: 'high',
                y: -25
            }
        }, {
            title: {
                text: secoText,
                rotation: 0,
                align: 'high',
                y: -25
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5],
            pointWidth: 10
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 220.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1],
            pointWidth: 5,
            yAxis: 1
        }]
    },

    function (chart) {
        var legend = chart.legend,
            group = legend.group,
            x = group.translateX;

        group.translate(x, chart.plotTop + chart.plotHeight - legend.legendHeight);

        var ticks = chart.yAxis[0].ticks,
            pos = chart.yAxis[0].tickPositions,
            top = pos[pos.length - 1].toString(),
            topX = ticks[top].label.xy.x,
            topString = ticks[top].label.element.innerHTML;

        hidden.text(topString);

        chart.yAxis[0].update({
            title: {
                x: topX - hidden.width() - 8
            }
        });
        chart.yAxis[1].update({
            title: {
                x: -10
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: In case of legend everything looks ok! Thank you very much! But with Y axis titles there is some problem. So, on your sample everything looks ok of course, but if you load data with different value range, than there is possibility that it would not be aligned properly (if labels would be shorter or longer). sample: http://jsfiddle.net/buks/0ur3L0pL/4/   (I've changed only 2 values in series data) Is there any way to calculate proper positions in analogical way as in your sample was calculated position of legend?

Comment: I've found javascript function that returns number of pixels of given text and its formatting. I used something  like this:             offset: 0 - getTextWidth('ppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp', '12px arial'),
and it looks that it is working ok in case of title of left y axis.

Answer (score 3):

Actually there is a `y` property for legend. 
What could probably cause your confusion is the fact that when you are not using `floating:true`, and try to render the legend in the middle of the plot, highcharts will ignore the y property since it could cause overlapping. when floating the legend this behaviour does not apply. you can see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/axfahe5u/2/

```
    legend: {
        align: 'center',
        floating:true,
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        y: -15
    },
```

and for the chart title you can simple set the properties for the `title` object, as below:

```
     title:{
         align:'left',
         x:-10
    },
```

you can  see the above fiddle for usage reference.

**In order to do it after chart was rendred**

Here I used a callback function that is called right after chart is rendred. 
You can use it differently in any other call.

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart:{
        marginLeft:170,  
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
            legend: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',


                floating:true,
            },
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

}, function(){
                //legend
                var legend = $('#container .highcharts-legend');
                var x = legend.position().left;
                var y = legend.position().top - 20;
                legend.attr({
                    transform: 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')'
                });
                //title
                var title = $('#container .highcharts-title');
                x = title.position().left-690;
                y = title.position().top;
                title.attr({
                    transform: 'translate(' + x + ',' + y + ')'
                });
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/3601/

Comment: Thank you for response. In case of prop 'Y' I meant that later, when I do for example assignment: [code]var legend=chart.legend[/code]   and then in object legend, property Y is not available. Or I do not know how to use it. I am beginner in case of javascript. That what you wrote works good when there is no category title. Is there any way to count Y value or the only way is to use fixed values (like you used: -15)?

Comment: Im not sure I fulldy understood you. please see the above edits, it might be useful.

Comment: Not fully :)  I meant category axis title, not chart title. I am getting error when I try to use: 'legend.position().left;' or 'legend.position().top ' Error: 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'position'

Comment: Not fully :)  I meant category axis title, not chart title. I am getting error when I try to use: 'legend.position().left;' or 'legend.position().top ' Error: 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'position'  When category axis title is set to visible, then  in your main example legend is placed below category axis title. http://jsfiddle.net/buks/8zem4jup/ Generally in the tool that I am developing user should have possibility to format chart as he want. That's why I wanted to calculate the position not to use fixed values.

Comment: Please provide a clear example of what your'e trying to achieve (maybe picture or something)

Comment: Ok, I provided it in the opening post.